# javascript array group with same field

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:
[image: console log of array]

The content in the array is fetched from an xml file which looks like this:
[image: xml file]

Is there a way to group array content, for eg, as you can see spotted dog is repeated three times because there are 3 dishes in it. I want my array to be like ["id", "spotted dog", "dish1","dish2","dish n++"]

I am stuck on this for quite a while so will appreciate your help.
This below code does gets xml file and shoots content in the array

```
                downloadUrl("php_to_xml.php",function(data){
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var array = [];
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("resdetails");
                var detail = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("detail1");

                for (r = 0; r < detail.length; r++){
                    var maindetail = detail[r].childNodes[0].getAttribute('name');
                    var mainid = markers[r].getAttribute('id');
                    var dish = detail[r].childNodes[1];
                    var attrname = dish.getAttribute("name");
                    for (j = 0; j<detail[r].childNodes.length;j++){
                        var info = detail[r].childNodes[j].getAttributeNode('dishname');
                        if (info != null){
                            var txt = info.nodeValue;
                            array.push([mainid,maindetail,txt]);                                
                        }
                    }   
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I couldn't test it)

```
for (r = 0; r < detail.length; r++){
    var maindetail = detail[r].childNodes[0].getAttribute('name');
    var mainid = detail[r].childNodes[0].getAttribute('id');

    var dishes=[];
    for (j = 1; j<detail[r].childNodes.length;j++){  // start at 1 because 0 should be resdetails
        var info = detail[r].childNodes[j].getAttributeNode('dishname');
        if (info != null){
            dishes.push(info.nodeValue); 
        }
    }
    array.push([mainid,maindetail,dishes]);  
}
```

This returns an array with each element being an array of mainid, maindetail and a nested array of all dishes.

Edit: or if you don't want the nested array, change the `array.push` to:

```
array.push([mainid,maindetail].concat(dishes));
```

Comment: i never knew can you can have nested arrays. cheers it worked exactly as i wanted it to work.

Comment: Haha, well you were already making a nested array yourself, because that's exactly what you did by doing `array.push([mainid,maindetail,txt]);`. `[mainid,...,txt]` is an array, and you `push` that array into `array` as a single element, thus giving you a nested array.

Comment: ohh yh make sence :P. but what i meant was to have an existing array (dishes) pushed in another array (array). I prefer having nested array because its easy to displaying all of the "dishes" array content by simply doing this - array[0][2], im lazy. But concat works fine too.